# SQL Server Management Studio can't connect to remote server anymore

Tags: ssms-2014

[image]

I used to just put my server name and my sql credentials to connect.  Now, not connecting.  My other domain login can connect to OTHER servers.

When I run the app in Development, it works.  Localhost it does not.  So, I know the server connection is good.  Something with my networking, after I got a new computer.

Comment: what was your login method?? window authentication or sql server authentication?

Comment: Use IP Address of mssql server instead of severname and try to connect again. You can check connection by telnet command : IP Address 1433

Comment: SQL server authentication.  I don't have the IP address yet.

Comment: This is a common problem, which I don't have right now.